# Unable to hit soap call

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```
<fault text:com.csd.dao.transaction.CustomHibernateTransactionManager cannot be cast to org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager>
```

I am using Hibernate 4.3.11.Final but still getting this error.

Comment: A full exception log will move better to describe the question.

Comment: @ Liping Huang There is no stack trace I found so only didn't attach any logs